# Can a react component have multiple areas for child content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a simple react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from "./index.css";

export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <header className={styles.root}>
        // area for child content
        {this.props.children}
      </header>
    );
  }
});
```

Now let's say that instead of one area for any child components, I'd want two, like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from "./index.css";

export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <header className={styles.root}>
        <div className={styles.logo}>
          // logo children here
        </div>
        <div>
          // navigation children here
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
});
```

I know that I could use attributes, but that wouldn't be very elegant for a large chunk of html content. How can this be done in react in a way that's similar to, for example, the [named blocks](https://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#inheritance) in swig?

---

Example of named blocks:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}My Page{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
  {% parent %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>This is just an awesome page.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

You see that these blocks can be used by referring to their name, and thus allow to 'yield' multiple areas of content. I'm hoping that there is a similarly elegant way in react to do this, as it makes components very composable.

Comment: When you say "I know I could use attributes" - do you mean props? Why wouldn't that be elegant?

Comment: Yeah, the properties that are defined in the tag `<ReactComponent property="a large amount of html here wouldn't be very maintainable" />`.

Comment: Your example of named blocks looks like Django, not swig?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make seperate components Donot use props to pass components as children. something like this.

header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from "./index.css";

export default React.createClass({
  getComponent(key) {
     return this.props.children.filter( (comp) => {
             return comp.key === key;
     });
  }
  render: function() {
    return (
      <header className={styles.root}>
        <div className={styles.logo}>
          {this.getComponent('logo')}
        </div>
        <div>
         {this.getComponent('navbar'}
    
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
});
```

app.js

```
export default React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <Header>
            <Logo key="logo"/>
            <Navbar key="navbar"/>
          </Header>
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: So a component can basically always only wrap a single entity? No way to pass it multiple pieces of content? Because that would mean that I'll have to do a lot of delving through components to figure out what child components they're composed of, whereas if I could pass an arbitrary amount of content areas I could theoretically have an overview of the entire arrangement of components/html in a single area.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a little closer to what I was looking for. Even though I can see how this could be confusing as there's no indication of which child goes where (unless you comment it or use declarative component names), and it's very easy to accidentally switch the order. The named blocks in swig make it very obvious which content goes where. I guess that does not have an equivalent in react? Something like named children instead of injecting them by array index?

Comment: check the code now i added a key to component logo and navbar and now i can loop through the props.children to find my appropriate one

Comment: How comes I get "this.props.children.filter is not a function" error?

Comment: @newman The filter function is for arrays. If this.props.children is a string or anything different from an array, then there is no filter function.

Answer (score 38):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from "./index.css";
import Logo from "./components/Logo";
import Navbar from "./components/Logo";

class Comp extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Header className={styles.root}
                top={Logo}
                right={Navbar}
                />
        );
    }
}

class  Header extends Component {
    render(){
        let {top,right} =this.props;
        return (
            <header className={styles.root}>
                <div className={styles.logo}>
                    {top && <top />}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {right && <right />}
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the right solution even the react documentation suggest taking this approach https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html is false the statement about to `Do not use props to pass components as children`


"Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to customize a component's look and behavior in an explicit and safe way. Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including primitive values, React elements, or functions."

Comment: This is the correct solution. Thanks @ncubica for the link.

Comment: If you're using Typescript, then this strategy (or the use of render props) is more typesafe than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat props as children, because technically `children` is just another prop. There's nothing wrong with this approach – React contributors themselves suggest you do that ([Support multiple child insertion points](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/848)).

In addition, if you're working in a big team of engineers, I would also suggest standardizing how you name those props as well as their standard behavior – are they just plain content or a callback you can pass arguments to. [react-placeholders](https://github.com/vladtsf/react-placeholders) can help you with that. So, the code of your component can look like that:

```jsx
// header.jsx
import React from 'react';
import withSlots from 'react-placeholders';

@withSlots('logo', 'navigation')
export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header className={styles.root}>
        <div className={styles.logo}>
          {this.props.header()}
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.props.navigation('home')}
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how you'd embed that component

```jsx
// app.jsx
import Header from 'header.jsx'

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header
        logoSlot={<img src="logo.svg" />}
        navigationSlot={(currentPage) => { 
          return <a href="#" style={{ color: currentPage ? 'blue' : 'red' }}>Home</a>
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That question inspired me. Here is my approach:

**First child component: TestA.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class TestA extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="TestA">{this.props.children}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Second child component: TestB.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class TestB extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="TestB">{this.props.children}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Parent component: TestAB.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';

type TestABProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default class TestAB extends React.Component<TestABProps> {

    //Loop through React nodes in children and get all instances of the specified component
    getComp( comp: string ): null | React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[] {
        if( this.props.children instanceof Array ) {
            let nodes: React.ReactNode[] = [];
            for( let child of this.props.children ) {
                if( ((child as React.ReactElement)?.type as Function)?.name == comp ) {
                    nodes.push( child );
                }
            }
            return nodes.length > 1 ? nodes : nodes[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="AB">
                <div className ="A">
                    {this.getComp("TestA")}
                </div>
                <div>This is a DIV between the components</div>
                <div className ="B">
                    {this.getComp("TestB")}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, you only have to place `{this.getComp("YourComponentName")}` where you want all the instances of this component to appear in your parent component.

**Usage example**

```
<TestAB>
    <TestA>Foo</TestA>
    <TestB>Bar</TestB>
    <TestA>Foobar</TestA>
</TestAB>
```

Usage is very simple and intuitive. No need for keys or anything else, just insert your child components without weird syntax.

**Resulting HTML**

```
<div class="AB">
    <div class="A">
        <div class="TestA">Foo</div>
        <div class="TestA">Foobar</div>
    </div>
    <div>This is a DIV between the components</div>
    <div class="B">
        <div class="TestB">Bar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that you can insert the children of TestAB in any order - they will be inserted in the right place.

All this can certainly be improved, you can adapt this to your needs. For example, if you put any child component other than TestA or TestB, they won't be displayed, that would be my first improvement.

Comment: I don't understand the -1. I answered the question and it works.